# Camera stuck on reload in Google cardboard + unity app

Tags: ios, xcode, unity-game-engine, google-cardboard

I am developing a simple VR app for iOS using the Google Cardboard SDK with the latest version of Unity. When I build the app and run it from XCode on my iPhone, it works fine, and the camera tracks as it should. However, if I relaunch the application, the camera becomes stuck and does not respond to movement of the phone. The app is not frozen, however, as I can still interact with the screen.

Interestingly, the camera becomes unstuck if I tap the settings gear icon in the bottom center of the screen, and then hit the back button. It also becomes unstuck if I simply hit the home button and then reopen the app (without relaunching it).

Has anyone faced a similar problem and know how to overcome it?

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

It seems that installing the Cardboard SDK into Unity added an extra "Cardboard" Game Object. My problem was fixed when I deleted that object.